# Nginx: What is causing this 301 redirect?

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301, daphne

I still don't know why my webpage is showing

```
myapp.com redirected you too many times.
```

Nginx is only used as a proxy for my django channels application, which is running with daphne.

Nginx is running with no errors.

```
myapp systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
```

Daphne is running on 127.0.0.1:8001

```
curl -I http://myapp.com/
curl -I https://myapp.com/
```

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 05 Mar 2019 11:53:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://myapp.com/

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 05 Mar 2019 11:54:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Location: https://myapp.com/
Connection: keep-alive
```

Does anyone know what is causing this 301 error?

Nginx config file

```
server {
listen 80;
servername myapp.com www.myapp.com;
servertokens off;
return 301 https://$servername$requesturi;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot  

root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {
    root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
}

location /media/  {
    root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri/ @python_django;
}

location @python_django {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure how to fix this completely, but when I take out

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

and run `curl -I -L http://www.myapp.com/` I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 05 Mar 2019 13:33:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 15:01:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5890a6b7-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

But I can't access the page because obviously LetsEncrypt is redirecting all `http` to `https` so I get referred back to the 301 error page!